# jquery range slider switch event listener

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I'm trying to create a button that can switch a jquery range slider from using the "inner values" to using the "outer values" and vice versa. All works well except for the event listener function. How would I change this?

The html I have:

```
<label for="direction" class="slider">Direction: <span class="swap-direction"></span></label>
<input id="direction" type="text" name="direction">
<div id="slider-direction"></div>
```

and the jquery I have:

```
$("#slider-direction").slider({
    range: true,
    min: 0,
    max: 359,
    values: [45, 300],
    step: 1,
    slide: function(event, ui){
        $("#direction").val(ui.values[1] + "deg  tot  " + ui.values[0] + "deg");
    }
});
$("#direction").val($("#slider-direction").slider("values", 1) + "deg  tot  " + $( "#slider-direction" ).slider("values", 0 ) + "deg" );
$('#slider-direction, #slider-direction .ui-slider-range').toggleClass('ui-widget-header ui-widget-content');
$('label.slider span.swap-direction').click(function(){
    $('#slider-direction, #slider-direction .ui-slider-range').toggleClass('ui-widget-header ui-widget-content');
    var richtingwaardes = $("#direction").val();
    var richtingwaardes = richtingwaardes.match(/\d+/g);


    $("#direction").val(richtingwaardes[1] + "deg  tot  " + richtingwaardes[0] + "deg");
    $("#slider-direction").on("slide", function(event, ui) {
        $("#direction").val(ui.values[1] + "deg  tot  " + ui.values[0] + "deg");
    });
});
```

Everything works fine except the event listener that is used when the slider is moved. I want that to switch as well. Anybody an idea?

Comment: I'm not sure that I understand what you're after, but is this it http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/u53En/?

Comment: Well, this does show my problem. When I click the button (a span actually) the values get reversed. However when I slide the slider after that the values go back to their original position